# HTML and PHP undefined index

Tags: php, html

Here is the code, it is telling me I have an undefined index which is weird because I already defined it with HTML code. Any way around this error? or any ways to make it better would be much appreciated...

```
<h1>make a username</h1>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo  
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"> 
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php 

$username = $_POST["username"];

echo $username;

?>
```

Comment: Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and initialize the variable $username at start with empty value

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST["username"]` will only be defined *after* you submit the form. When you first load the page (with an http GET), `$_POST["username"]` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

After form submission it will work. You should try this:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["username"])){
        $username = $_POST["username"];
    }

?>

<h1>make a username</h1>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo  
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"> 
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo (isset($username))? $username: ''; ?>">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php
    echo (isset($username))? $username: '';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do following changes to your code :

```
<h1>make a username</h1>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo  
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"> 
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php 
/// This portion of code will execute only after you hit submit button
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
$username = $_POST["username"];

echo $username;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`if ( isset( $_POST["username"] ) ){`

```
$username = $_POST["username"];

} else{

$username = '';

}
echo $username;
```

Try this code instead of your php code. This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST["username"];
add an @ before this,@$_POST['username'],'@' will ignore this error